# Gerund Phrases after adjectives

Tags: grammar

In this sentence, "It's difficult being an architect", is "being an architect" a gerund phrase and, if so, is it the subject?

Answer (score 1):

You can call ***it*** a subject, if you want to. It behaves like a subject - verb agreement, word order, undergoes Raising, etc. But it has no meaning, and it's a dummy, inserted by the syntactic transformation [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299).

You can also call the extraposed clause ***being an architect*** a subject, if you want to. It's meaningful, unlike *it*, and it also appears as subject in the non-extraposed sentence

- *Being an architect is difficult.*

which means the same thing.

That's because the transformation changes the subject, but doesn't change the meaning. Syntactic transformations like Extraposition or Passive don't change meanings. The various jobs of subject are parcelled out among two constituents in this sentence, and neither has all of them. So which one should get the label isn't clear, and that's because the label itself isn't clear -- "subject" is a term invented by ancient grammarians, not something you can discover scientifically.

Comment: Indeed and it is the transformation that makes the analysis possible.

Answer (score 0):

The *it* here is a [dummy pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun) and is, therefore, <sub>([debatable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun#Dissenting_views))</sub> the subject of the sentence.

You can argue that it refers to "being an architect".

Answer (score 0):

> It's difficult *being an architect.*

Here, *being an architect* is a Gerund-Participle clause. The subject of the sentence is *it*, and *being an architect* is an *Extraposed Subject*.

*being an architect* is not a phrase, it's a clause. It has it's own verb, object and an implicit subject.

Answer (score 0):

> It's difficult being an architect.

*It* is a dummy subject.  The real subject is *being an architect*, a gerund phrase.

The clause means

> Being an architect is difficult.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects) explains dummy subjects.

> Sometimes we need to use a ‘dummy’ or ‘empty’ or ‘artificial’ subject when there is no subject attached to the verb, and where the real subject is somewhere else in the clause.

> **It**’s always interesting **to find out about your family history**.

> The real subject...is ‘to find out about your family history’.